# Typescript - return type conditions

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

This question is focused on Typescript usage in React.

I have two React hooks: `useStatus(): Status` and `useResult(): Result | null` and use them like:

```
const status = useStatus();
const result = useResult();

if (status !== "success") {
  return <Loading />;
}

return ... something using result ...;
```

I can change the signature of both functions (parameters and return type).
I can't change the position of the `useResult` call (it has to be before `if`) - that's React's only constraint.

Conceptually, I know `result` will not be `null` if `status` is `"success"`. I'd like to somehow encode this information in return type. That way, Typescript would somehow know at last line, that `status` is `"success"` so `result` is `Result` (not `Result | null`).

I know I can separate in two different components - that's what I'm already doing, but curious if I can avoid that.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Thanks! :)

Comment: Why don't you combine the two hooks into one?

Comment: Here you can find some info about handling unions in React https://catchts.com/unions

Comment: Just wanted to make the same comment as above. If you need to do extra effort to sort out your types then most likely there is some conceptional problem with the code. In this case there are two separate hooks delivering data from the same source if I understood correctly. You just need to comine these hooks into one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A first refactor could be to extract the handling of those two hooks into a dedicated hook with it's own return type.

Afterwards you might (if possible) follow the advice in the comments and move whatever `useStatus` and `useResult` *do* directly into that new hook.

For example:

```
// mock types
type Status = 'loaded' | 'loading';
type Result = unknown;

// hooks per your description
declare function useStatus(): Status;
declare function useResult(): Result | null;

// new type
// ref: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#discriminating-unions
type Response =
  | { status: 'loaded'; result: Result; }
  | { status: 'no-result'; }
  | { status: 'loading'; };

// new hook
const useResponse = (): Response => {
  const status = useStatus();
  const result = useResult();

  if ('loaded' === status) {
    return null === result
      ? {status: 'no-result'}
      : {status, result};
  }

  return {status: 'loading'};
};
```

Using this hook will allow you to savely access it's return properties:

```
const App: React.FC = () => {
  const response = useResponse();

  switch (response.status) {
    case 'loading':
      return <div>Loading</div>;

    case 'no-result':
      return <div>Failure...</div>;

    case 'loaded':
      return <WithResult result={response.result}/>;
  }
};
```

---

Ref: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#discriminating-unions

Comment: tnx! 

i'm just curious, is there a way to make this work:

const { status, result } = useResponse();

Comment: @MatijaFolnovic It would be possible yes, but I'd argue that it's a bit unclean. You would need to add `result: null | undefined` (or any other fallback type you want) to each Response type without a result (e.g. `| { status: 'no-result'; result: null; }`. Further, when creating a response in `useResponse` you'd need to make sure to include this default value wherever appropriate (e.g. `? {status: 'no-result'; result: null;}`). Another option would be to provide a default when using the hook, e.g. `const {status, result} = {result: null, ...useResponse()};`.